# Read pdf with minimum white margin

Tags: pdf, printing, adobe-acrobat, pdf-reader, pdftk

I have a pdf file which originates from MS Word (*.docx).

I want to read / print it out with minimum white margin.

I have tried converting the pdf file back to *.docx. Although I can edit the white margin in *.docx, as the file contains formulae and special symbols, the converted document displays distorted alignments and layout.

I am using Adobe Acrobat XI.

Is there a way to make the pdf with minimum white margin, for reading or printing?

Comment: Do you have access to the *original* document in Word .docx format?

Comment: No since it is forwarded by the others.

Answer (score 1):

Crop the PDF document so that the margins are removed/trimmed.

In case any one using adobe acrobat is in need, try the following: Look for "Remove White Margins" [helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/crop-pdf-pages.html](http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/crop-pdf-pages.html)

For non acrobat users, try Sejda's [crop PDF online](https://www.sejda.com/crop-pdf).

Comment: Thanks. In case any one using adobe acrobat is in need, try the following:

Look for "Remove White Margins"

https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/crop-pdf-pages.html

Comment: I added your details to the answer so they are easier to find.